# Guardar una referencia en un campo de clase desde el constructor en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente clase solo ilustrativa, quiero almacenar una referencia dentro de un campo de clase, para modificar el valor usando metodos en dicha clase, he intentado varias cosas:
[How do I assign by "reference" to a class field in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980463/how-do-i-assign-by-reference-to-a-class-field-in-c)
y [Cannot use ref or out parameter in lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions)

```
public class myClass
{


    ref float myFloat;
    public myClass(ref float myOutFloat)
    {
    myFloat = myOutFloat;
    }



    public void changeFloat(float value)
    {
    myFloat = value;
    }


}
```

y quiero que suceda lo siguiente:

```
float value = 0;
myClass iClass = new myClass(value);
iClass.changeFloat(5);
print(value); //Se deberia imprimir un 5
```

Como podría lograr dicho comportamiento?

Comment: Me temo que no puedes guardar una referencia a un int en tu clase. Lo mejor que puedes hacer algo similar a lo que hace java, crear una clase wrapper para envolver el entero. Checa esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260915/hold-reference-to-int-in-c-sharp es muy similar a la tuya pero con un int.

Comment: Checa este demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/hHWnAB

Comment: Las variables ya son referencias al valor...

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas confundido un poco con los valores como referencia.

**Sugiero que lo hagas de la siguiente manera:**

Genera una clase normal con atributos y constructores normales, pero en el método de `changeFloat`, le agregas la referencia para que te devuelva el valor de tu atributo principal:

```
public class myClass
{
    public float myFloat { get; set; }
    public myClass(ref float myOutFloat)
    {
        myFloat = myOutFloat;
    }

    public void changeFloat(ref float value)
    {
        myFloat = value;
    }
}
```

Y cuando te toque llamar a la clase con su método, pues lo harías de la siguiente manera:

```
float value = 0;
myClass iClass = new myClass(value);
value = 5;
iClass.changeFloat(ref value);
Console.WriteLine(value); //Se imprime un 5
```

¿Qué sucede con lo que intentas hacer?:

1. Estas tratando de tener un atributo de referencia en tu clase, lo cual para qué podría servir? La idea es que sea un valor por referencia, no instanciarlo, entonces lo importante es que se use como tal, como un parámetro de algún método que sirva para transportar un valor por referencia.
2. Agregas una referencia en el constructor, esto es algo que puedes usar en caso de que el constructor se cree cuando tiene algún valor, pero cuando usas el segundo método para actualizar el valor de `myFloat` pues no estas enviándole el parámetro por referencia.

Para que lo entiendas de una mejor manera prueba con lo siguiente:

```
float value = 4;
myClass iClass = new myClass(ref value);
Console.WriteLine(value); //Se imprime un 4
value = 5;
iClass.changeFloat(ref value);
Console.WriteLine(value); //Se imprime un 5

float value2 = 0;
myClass iClass2 = new myClass(ref value);
Console.WriteLine(value2); //Se imprime un 0
value2 = 6;
iClass2.changeFloat(ref value2);
Console.WriteLine(value2); //Se imprime un 6
```